# Activate worksheet on created workbook in Excel JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins

It's possible to create and open new workbook using Excel JavaScript API using [`Excel.createWorkbook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-createworkbook-function(1))

Is there a way to activate a specific worksheet on this newly created workbook? The current `context` belongs to the original workbook that currently exists in the runtime.

Comment: Perhaps you might have better luck using something else other than office-js, like Sheets.JS?

Answer (score 1):

That can't be done. An add-in running in the context of one workbook cannot call out to another one.